# Concatenate two dates in SQL, just like we do in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server

In excel if we concat 2 dates for e.g `1/1/2015` and `7/1/2018` by using the formula `=CONCAT(1/1/2015,"_",7/1/2018)` the result is `42005_43282`.

Can we do the same thing in SQL?

Comment: Which is it? MySQL or SQLServer?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer for the above question.

```
SELECT CONCAT (CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1/1/2015')) + 2, '_', CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(DATETIME, '7/1/2018')) + 2)
```

Output: `42005_43282`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do this operation also in SQL server.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10),CAST(CONVERT(datetime,'1/1/2015') as float))+ '_' 
+convert(varchar(10),CAST(CONVERT(datetime,'7/1/2018') as float))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing in TSQL using concat also.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `concat` May be part of the solution, but OP wants the dates converted to numbers too.

Comment: But using concat in sql is giving me the below output.                                          
select CONCAT(1/2/2015,'_',7/1/2018)                                                           
output-    0_0